# How to access my total x translation within a pan gesture recognizer and access it from XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uigesturerecognizer

I'm setting up a pan gesture recognizer that, when panning with two fingers, moves the view contained in it. I want to provide event triggers when the view has moved a specified amount in the X direction, which requires the total displacement to be sent to my XAML page every time it is changed in the gesture recognizer class. I am having trouble accessing the total x displacement outside of the gesture recognizer class.

I have tried using a delegate and event handler to get the .TranslationX or TotalX values from within the class, but cannot seem to figure out how to do so. Every approach I try does not update the value as I pan the view. Below is my Gesture Container class. I just need to access the total x displacement every time it changes outside this class.

```
public class GestureContainer : ContentView
{
    public GestureContainer()
    {
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.TouchPoints = 2;
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                Content.TranslationX =
                e.TotalX;
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                ViewExtensions.TranslateTo(Content, 0, 0, 250, null);
                break;
        } 
    }
}
```

I am very new to C# and Xamarin, so I apologize if the solution is an obvious one. I'm just not sure how to approach this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to provide event triggers when the view has moved a specified amount in the X direction, which requires the total displacement to be sent to my XAML page every time it is changed in the gesture recognizer class. I am having trouble accessing the total x displacement outside of the gesture recognizer class.

If you want to get view TranslationX and TranslationY after you move view, I do one sample you can take a look:

Firstly, you can create a pan container,contains a generalized helper class that performs freeform panning.

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }


    public PanContainer ()
    {
        // Set PanGestureRecognizer.TouchPoints to control the 
        // number of touch points needed to pan
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer ();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add (panGesture);
    }

    void OnPanUpdated (object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType) {

        case GestureStatus.Running:
            // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
            Content.TranslationX = Math.Max (Math.Min (0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs (Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
            Content.TranslationY = Math.Max (Math.Min (0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs (Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));    
            break;

        case GestureStatus.Completed:
            // Store the translation applied during the pan
            x = Content.TranslationX;
            y = Content.TranslationY;
                Console.WriteLine("TranslationX is {0}",x);
                Console.WriteLine("Translationy is {0}", y);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then shows the PanContainer wrapping an one element, here I use Image element.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <local:PanContainer x:Name="pan1">
            <Image
                x:Name="image1"
                HeightRequest="1024"
                Source="MonoMonkey.jpg"
                WidthRequest="768" />

        </local:PanContainer>

        <Label x:Name="labelx" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference image1}, Path=TranslationX}" />
        <Label
            x:Name="labely"
            Margin="30"
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference image1}, Path=TranslationY}" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

You can use bind to get image TranslationX and TranslationY.

[image]